# Multiselect as a Button Group

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've been spinning my wheels trying to figure out the best practice for a field with multiple values in redux form.

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Where that those buttoms are custom components.  I have it working visually, using a custom component and `onChange` to update the redux value of a hidden checkbox field.

This seems like a fairly common usecase as it is essentially a multiselct.  I know the docs roccomend using react-widgets multiselect but it dosen't seem that those will fit the button group styling that I am trying to accomplish.  Here is what I have so far, but seeing as redux-form views checkbox's as boolean values rather than arrays, I don't think this is going to work for me.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Field} from 'redux-form'
import * as icons from './../MultiSelectBtnGrid/icons'

const btnStyles = {
  border: '3px solid #f6e9db',
  background: 'transparent',
  borderRadius: '45px',
  width: '250px'
}

const btnSelectedStyles = {
  border: '3px solid #27313c',
  background: 'transparent',
  borderRadius: '45px',
  width: '250px'
}

class MultiSelectField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {selected: false}
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected})
    this.props.input.onChange(!this.state.selected)
  }

  render() {
    const {content, idx, input: {name}} = this.props
    const {selected} = this.state
    return (
      <div className={'row m-auto rel'}>
        <button type={'button'} className={`mb-1 p-3 ml-auto mr-auto`} style={selected ? btnSelectedStyles : btnStyles}
                onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {content}
          <span style={{position: 'absolute', right: '15px', top: '0', bottom: '0', margin: 'auto'}}
                className={'mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'}>{icons.plusIcon(selected)}</span>
        </button>
        <input type={'checkbox'} name={`${name}`} value={selected ? 'test' : null} checked={selected} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class MultiSelectBtnGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {selected: props.formState.values[props.name]}
  }

  render() {
    const {options, name} = this.props
    return (
      <div className={'container'}>
        <div className={'row'}>
          {options.map((option, idx) => {
            return <Field
              component={MultiSelectField}
              name={name}
              type='checkbox'
              content={option.content}
              key={idx}
              {...this.props}
              className={'col'}
              idx={idx}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiSelectBtnGroup` should be the `Field`'s component making the value an array in the form's state.

Here is an example:

```
const MultiSelectBtnGroup = { input, options } => {
    const values = input.value || [];

    const handleClick = (value, select) => {
        var index = values.indexOf(value);

        if (select) {
            if (index === -1) {
                input.onChange([...values, value]);
            }
        } else {
            if (index !== -1) {
                input.onChange(values.filter(v => v !== value));
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="row">
            {options.map(o => {
                const selected = values.indexOf(o.value) !== -1;
                return (
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="row m-auto rel">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                className="mb-1 p-3 ml-auto mr-auto"
                                style={selected ? btnSelectedStyles : btnStyles}
                                onClick={e => handleClick(o.value, !selected)}
                            >
                                {o.content}
                                <span
                                    style={{ position: 'absolute', right: '15px', top: 0, bottom: 0, margin: 'auto' }}
                                    className="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                                >
                                    {icons.plusIcon(selected)}
                                </span>
                            </button>

                            <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name={name}
                                value={o.value}
                                checked={selected}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

const Example = { options, name } => (
    <div className="container">
        <Field component={MultiSelectField} name={name} />
    </div>
);
```

The `<input>` does not need to be there to maintain the form state but it can be helpful if you want to submit the form traditionally.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was super helpful!